# Blender 3.3 bug? Making random changes to my geometry when changing levels viewport using subdivision modifier

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, subdivision-surface

In edit mode trying to model a specific object while using subdivision modifier, blender all of a sudden started crashing momentarily and changing my geometry whenever I change the number of viewport levels which I like to switch between 0 and 1 or 2 to see how it looks. It only seems to happen with a specific object in my project, which was working normally at one point but suddenly started acting buggy when trying to fix circle faces using the knife tool. Initially I thought maybe I just needed to upgrade my driver or maybe reduce vertices but after discovering how it adds new vertices to my geometry I'm pretty confused and annoyed that I now have to go back and fix those areas as well as worry about blender adding more random vertices. Here's some pictures of the added vertices here, specifically the areas where there are many vertices: [image: added vertices][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what the issue was but I updated drivers, upgraded to blender 3.3.1, fixed all the added vertices before using the subdivision modifier again and now its working properly with no crashes or randomly added vertices when using the subdivision modifier.